# how can i fix my increment in instr with vba

Tags: vba, excel

how can i fix my increment every time when i use instr with vba, my code works perfect and find the string im looking for but its not incrementing right, instead of doing it once , its doing it twice and ends at rows 12 which is my last row. i understand its stop at my lastrow which is 12 but i dont understand why is it incrementing twice when i say incrementing twice thats mean first find all my string which is 4 of them then its goes back to the first one and kept on doing it until lastrow which is 12, here is my code and my range looks like after i run it 
1N_ra01_68K
1N_ra01_K
1N_ra01_70K
1N_ra01_88K
1N_ra01_K
1N_ra01_70K
1N_ra01_88K
1N_ra01_70K
1N_ra01_88K
1N_ra01_88K
1N_ra01_88K just to remind yo my rows stars at 2 and ends at 12

```
sub find()
    dim i as long, x as string, y as long, Sheet1rows as long
    x = "ra01"
    y = 2
    Sheet1rows = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    For i = y To Sheet1rows
        If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3), x) > 0 Then
           Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F" & y) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)
           y = y + 1
        End If
    Next i  
end sub
```

Comment: Using y to set i, and then changing the value of y within your for loop can possibly cause some problems.

Comment: Can you explain what it's meant to do, and what you are getting instead? there are two variables being incremented : `y` and `i`. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: This code appears to be working at least as far as I can tell. If you're getting unexpected results, please describe your specific problem in more detail. I don't see any observable difference if I do `For i = 2 to Sheet1Rows` or `For i = y to Sheet1Rows`.  Using the counter `y` is OK in this context because VBA doesn't otherwise support parallel iteration.

Comment: y just a variable assign a number which is 2 n  start my 2nd rows i can just right it like this 2 to sheet1rows and when i wrote .range("F" & y) i can just replace 2 instead of y basically what im trying to say my second line after finds the instr increment by 1 which is y = y + 1 cause my rows start at 2 and first row is my header i hope its clear everything

Comment: i did described it twice and if you see all the way in the top i have my output result @DavidZemens

Comment: Just to point out the comparison statement `If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3), x) > 0 Then` could be written in format `If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value Like ("*" & x & "*") Then`. The **Like** operator compares two values and returns a boolean value. In comparison operations it's generally better way to do it than **InStr**. There is also "undeclared" variable Sheet1rows in your code. For avoiding type mismatch and possible run out of range errors you should declare this variable for example `Dim Sheet1rows as interger`

Comment: I think I answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521977/using-instr-to-find-values-in-vba/24522440#24522440 but from a different user.

Comment: i checked it and doesn't work

Comment: no, you didn't adequately describe it as far as I'm concerned. Also, showing us the output is not particularly helpful without also showing us the **input**. How are we supposed to test this and troubleshoot for you?  You say "find all my string which is 4 of them " but the code you provide only searches for **one** string (assigned the variable name `x`).  What does that mean?  Please add more detail if you want to get any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this...

```
For i = y To Sheet1rows
        If InStr(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3), x) > 0 Then
           Sheets("Sheet3").Range("F" & y) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)
          y = y + 1
         End If
    Next
```

Comment: its working i just had to define individual variable for all my loops thanks guys