# using instr to find values in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am using instr function to find values within a range in **vba** and when I look for my string which is `"ra01"` , it is finding it and working perfect, but it is not incrementing by 1. What I mean by that in my *sheet1*, *range C*

```
row2 ( 2_x_ra01_ff string), 
row3 ( ff_x_xxxx_ff), row4 (xxxxxxx), 
row5 (fffffff) row6 ( 1_f_ra01_xx) 
row7 (dfdfdfd) row8(f_x_ra01_xx)
```

These are the strings so when I try to paste the finding values into *sheet2*, it is copying and pasting pefect but not incremeting right, instead my *sheet2* looks like this `row2( 2_x_ra01_ff string)` then `row3 empty row4 empty row5 empty row6( 1_f_ra01_xx)` and so on. So how come it is not pasting it in `row3` or `row4` or `row5`, why is it choosing the exact same rows from *sheet1*. Here is my code you will have better understand if you run it.

```
Sub find()
    Dim x As String, i As Long, lastrow As Long, y As Long
    x = "ra01"
    y = 2

    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.InStr(i, 6).Value = x Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & y) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
              y = y + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think there's a syntax error in your code. Also, to get what you want, don't use the same variable `i` in your destination sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Sub find()
    Dim x As String, i As Long, lastrow As Long, y As Long
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    x = "ra01"

    With sh1
        lastrow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If InStr(.Range("F" & i).Value, x) <> 0 Then
                .Range("A" & i).Copy _
                sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

HTH.

Comment: thanks all i had to do change my variables and define individual variables for each loops and perfect